# EF Importing Oracle View

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

I am using VS2013, Entity Framework 5, and Oracle 11g.

There is a view in the database that returns data from two tables:

```
create or replace view v_test
as
select 
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
from table1
union
select
    column1,
    column2,
    column3
from table2
```

Column1 from both tables are PK.

When I try to import that view into EF, EF complains about the view without a primary key and couldn't be imported.

Therefore, I try to create a primary key for the view using the following:

```
alter view v_test add constraint v_test_pk primary key(column1) disable novalidate;
```

However, I got the same EF warning about no PK and the view couldn't be imported.

Is there a way to import the view into EF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. The best I been able to come up with is to add row number as primary key.

With EF5 and Oracle 11g you might get away with just adding a primary key constraint to row number.

However if you use anything newer you'll get the error "primary key is nullable". To get around that I created a Row_Number table and joined the view to that so that row number is an actual primary key.

It's a bit complicated but I haven't found anything easier yet.

Some setup code and a sample use for a view:

```
CREATE TABLE "ROW_NUMBER" 
   (                  "ROW_NUMBER" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
                       CONSTRAINT "ROW_NUMBER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ROW_NUMBER"));
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_ROW_NUMBER IS
LOOP_ROW_NUMBER NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN  
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO ROW_NUMBER(ROW_NUMBER)
    VALUES (LOOP_ROW_NUMBER);
    LOOP_ROW_NUMBER := LOOP_ROW_NUMBER + 1;
    IF LOOP_ROW_NUMBER > 1000000 THEN
    EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END CREATE_ROW_NUMBER;
```

---

```
begin
  CREATE_ROW_NUMBER;
end;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW New_View (“ID”, [COLUMNS]) AS 
  SELECT Row_Number.Row_Number, [COLUMNS]
  FROM Row_Number INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT ROWNUM Row_Number, [COLUMNS]
    FROM(
                      SELECT * FROM Table1
                      UNION 
                      SELECT * FROM Table2
   ) Original_View 
  ON Row_Number.Row_Number = Original_View.Row_Number;
```